# Login and logout in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using PHP and Zend Framwwork for developing web apps, and i want to implement login and logout concept in my application.In first step I create the auth adapter that is working well and authenticating the users.
                      There is a menu bar in the application where i have an anchor tag for login. After clicking the login link the login page appears.
                      Now my question is, I want that when the user login with his/her valid credentials, then the login text in menu changes to logout and when user logout it changes back to login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such task, I have profileLink view helper that checks if a user is logged or not, and displays appropriate message:

```
/**
 * ProfileLink helper
 *
 * Call as $this->profileLink() in your layout script
 */
class My_View_Helper_ProfileLink extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {


     /**
     * View instance
     *
     * @var  Zend_View_Interface
     */
    public $view;


    public function profileLink()  {

        $baseUrl = $this->view->baseUrl();

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        $html = '<a href="'.$baseUrl.'/login">'. $this->view->translate('Login') .'</a>';

        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) { 
            // here have to make amendments to what you have 
            // in your identity.
            $identity = $auth->getIdentity();                        
            $fname = $identity->property->nickname; 
            $url = $this->view->baseUrl('/user');
            $fnameLink = "<a href=\"$url\"/>$fname</a>";
            $html = $fnameLink . ' <span>|</span> <a href="'.$baseUrl.'/logout">'
                . $this->view->translate('Logout') . '</a>' ;
        }   

        return $html;
    }


     /**
     * Get Zend_View instance
     *
     * @param Zend_View_Interface $view
     */
    public function setView(Zend_View_Interface $view) {
        $this->view = $view;
    }

}
```

Whit this, in the layout.phtml I just have:

```
<?php echo $this->profileLink(); ?>
```

The view helpers is modified version of one that I found somewhere in the net ( i don't have a link to the original version).

Hope this will  be useful to you.

Comment: My view helper functions similarly, of course. But in the logged-out case, I display links for login and registration; in the logged-in case, I display links for profile and logout.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Zend Framework 1.12 you found an error message something like this:

**Plugin by name 'ProfileLink' was not found in the registry;**

To solve this problem I have replace **My** with **Zend** hope this will help you.